# why <th> or <td> border is not showing ( I used Jquery UI resizable() function on these <th> or <td>) in mozilla and IE, but works fine for chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the screen shot of my table where the two [th] and two [td] are made resizable by jquery-ui resizable() function.
I used Jquery-1.10.2 and Jquery-ui 1.10.2.
Now the border is fine for Chrome, but doesn't show on IE or Mozilla

Chrome ScreenShot:
[image: Chrome ScreenShot:]

Mozilla or IE ScreenShot:
[image: Mozilla or IE ScreenShot:]

The code for these two table is here below:

```
<table style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 41, 135); position: relative;">
    <tr>
       <th class="ui-resizable" style="height: 25px; width: 120px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 41, 135);text-align: center;">
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
       </th>
       <th class="ui-resizable" style="height: 25px; width: 120px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 41, 135); text-align: center;">
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="ui-resizable" style="height: 25px; width: 120px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 41, 135); text-align: center;">
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
       </td>
       <td class="ui-resizable" style="height: 25px; width: 120px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(0, 41, 135); text-align: center;">
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
          <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Don't use tables to build your page structure. Use them only for tabular data. What you're looking for is [border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp).

Comment: I need to do this in table, it works fine in google crome but not working in mozilla firefox. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to do this in a table, event though you know it's semantically wrong and it's prone to unpredictable rendering results and cross-browser compatibility issues?

Comment: My requirement is to resize table cell by mouse dragging so i need to use table. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: The correct answer is: do not use table tag for page structure, especially if this is a homework exercise some teacher gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery ui resizable function is making your table cell border collapsed. You can add the style border-collapse:initial in table tag, so your border will be visible.

CSS:

```
table{
border-collapse:initial;
}
```

or 
add this property inline.

Answer (score 0):

Putting that code in a pen produces perfect borders in all browsers, so I presume some CSS rules you're not aware of are causing this behaviour. Check with F12 in Mozilla, IE and Chromewhich CSS files are being loaded and which CSS rules are affecting the table.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not correct.

In first row second **th** instead of closing the **`</th>`** you wrote **`</td>`**. Please change this. If the HTML code is properly written then it will work fine in all the browser.

FYI: I tried in IE8, FF[35.0.1] and Chrome [Version 40.0.2214.94 ] and its working fine in all 3 browser